# inline asm to x64 - understanding

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, assembly, visual-studio-2015

need some help understanding what this inline asm does (c++) so that I can properly convert it so that I can compile for x64.  inline asm is not possible with Visual Studio and x64.  my research tells me that I should use intrinics OR put the inline asm into an asm file and put that asm file in my project.

as you can I really do not know what I am talking about here but you should get the general idea.

I really would like to understand how to get this inline asm to work in either x86 or x64 compiled code.  if i could understand what this is doing then maybe i could convert to c++.  or move this inline asm to an asm file.  i sort of know how to move to a separate file.  the problem with moving to asm file is that i am not sure how to setup my asm function to accept the parameter i need to pass to it.  i would like the easy answer where someone just does this for me BUT what i need is an explanation so that i can in the future i can do this on my own.  i have two blocks of inline asm and this appears to be the easier of the two.

[inline asm to asm file](https://deviorel.wordpress.com/2015/01/19/compiling-64-bit-assembler-code-in-visual-studio-2014/)

```
// FIRST inline asm talked about above
// little endian
void BlockInc(unsigned char *data)
{
    #if DATA_BLOCK_SIZE==16
    __asm
    {
        mov edi,[data]
        add dword ptr [edi+0],1
        adc dword ptr [edi+4],0
        adc dword ptr [edi+8],0
        adc dword ptr [edi+12],0
    }
    #else
#error
    #endif
}

//this is the second more difficult inline asm not mentioned
void concThread(void *param)
{
    unsigned long threadN = *((unsigned long *)param);

    while(true)
    {
        unsigned long           index;

        // 1. synch
        WaitForSingleObject(concThread_semaphores1[threadN],INFINITE);
        ReleaseSemaphore(concThread_semaphores2[threadN],1,NULL);

        if(sharedStop)
        {
            _endthread();
        }

        // start "sharedValue" concurrent modify
        while(!sharedOkToGo);

        for(index=0;index<(CYCLE_NUM/128);index++)
        {
            LARGE_INTEGER   li;

            QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);

            if(threadN%2)
            {
                __asm
                {
                    movzx ecx,byte ptr [li]
                    jecxz LOOP0_PREHEAD
                    jmp LOOP0_HEAD

                    LOOP0_PREHEAD:
                    inc ecx
                    LOOP0_HEAD:
                    dec sharedValue
                    loop LOOP0_HEAD
                }
            }
            else
            {
                __asm
                {
                    movzx ecx,byte ptr [li]
                    jecxz LOOP1_PREHEAD
                    jmp LOOP1_HEAD

                    LOOP1_PREHEAD:
                    inc ecx
                    LOOP1_HEAD:
                    inc sharedValue
                    loop LOOP1_HEAD
                }
            }
        }

        ReleaseSemaphore(concThread_semaphores2[threadN],1,NULL);
    }
}
```

EDITED asm: comment below suggested it wasn't correctly written.

Comment: This is one of the reason inline assembly is not recommended for x86, and not supported for x64 or ARM. This code is written to optimize for some ancient platform when it would probably be faster as C++.

Comment: could you suggest a way to accomplish this same thing but with c++?

Comment: I doubt this assembly the second block was ever optimal for any platform and its not at all clear if does anything useful at all. You need to figure out what its supposed to and if it actually supposed to be useful completely rewrite it to use atomic operations as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, the code is wrong. Given that `inc` does not modify the carry flag, the following `adc` will use the initial zero value of it so it will never carry to the second dword.

That said, if you want to convert this code yourself, you will of course need an instruction set reference to see what each instruction does. In this case apparently it wants to increment a 128 bit number.

Comment: how can this code be modified to actually work the way you suggest it should?  I was able to separate this from inline to an asm file BUT my x64 rewrite is not going so well.  I will post that later!

Comment: Instead of the `inc dword ptr [edi+ 0]` you should use `add dword ptr [edi+ 0], 1` and you can delete the `clc`. The standalone 64 bit version is just 3 instructions: `add qword ptr [rcx], 1; adc qword ptr [rcx+8], 0; ret`.

Comment: .code

BlockIncrement PROC, var1:QWORD

 mov rdi,var1
 add qword ptr [rcx],1
 adc qword ptr [rcx+8],0
 ret

BlockIncrement ENDP

END

Answer (score 1):

This

```
movzx ecx,byte ptr [li]
jecxz LOOP0_PREHEAD
jmp LOOP0_HEAD

LOOP0_PREHEAD:
inc ecx
LOOP0_HEAD:
dec sharedValue
loop LOOP0_HEAD
```

looks like

```
// ecx was used to hold a loop count
uint32_t i = li;
// do-while to guarantee execution at least once
// since LOOP0_PREHEAD incremented ecx if it was zero
do {
   sharedValue--;
   i--;
} while (i > 0);
```

Comment: Since the code looks like it's doing some sort of test/verification on multiple threads accessing the same memory location (`sharedValue`), I believe the purpose of the asm in the original is to ensure that memory accesses aren't reordered, deferred, or optimized away. In MSVC++ accessing `sharedValue` through a `volatile` reference might give similar results. It's also possible that they wanted to ensure that `sharedValue` is updated using `dec` and `inc` which provide some atomicity. Using the C operators might not map to `inc`/`dec` at the machine level.

Comment: @MichaelBurr If `std::atomic` is available, `std::atomic<int64_t> sharedValue;` and then `sharedValue.fetch_sub(1);` might be preferable?

Comment: Definitely - I should have thought to mention that.

Comment: yes that last bit of inline is testing multiple threads.  exactly how its doing this I have no clue because I do not understand the asm at all.  the inline is in code that is doing some sort of verification with threads.  your description sounds likely.

Comment: I could remove this inline and replace with the do while?

Comment: @AaronSulwer I wanted to specific about what kind of integer to use, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: LARGE_INTEGER is actually __int64 (windows).  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383713.aspx

Comment: @J.J.Hakala  sorry I had a duh moment just now.  thanks!